# hard code custom field for custom post type in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a custom post type in wordpress called videos. When the admin adds a video he also needs to provide a youtube-id. This can be done by selecting the appropriate custom field from the drop-down list and then entering the ID.

I was wondering though, isn't there a way to always display that custom field when you are adding or editing a video? (And optionally, could you even make it a required field?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just answer my own question after 8 years :)

For people who live on another planet: just use the [ACF plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [More Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/) or [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugins to create the youtube-id field for your video posts.

Comment: thanks. I found something better though. You can pretty easily just add the extra fields while you register a new post type, using add_meta_box(). http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/rock-solid-wordpress-3-0-themes-using-custom-post-types/comment-page-3/#comment-364170

Answer (score 0):

[Youtube Post Type](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/youtube-post-type/) also requires a youtube url before creating a custom post type draft.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Meta Fields for youtube video url

By using

`add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $post_type, $context, $priority, $callback_args );`

[Example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)